# General result for rings in which irreducible is prime?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

There is a general result that characterizes the rings in which prime is equivalent to irreducible?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is a domain, primes are always irreducible. If $A$ is a noetherian domain, then irreducibles are primes if and only if $A$ is an UFD.

In fact, if $A$ is an UFD, it is easy to check that an irreducible is prime. On the converse, if $A$ is a noetherian domain, we can always factorize an element $x$ in irreducibles (one starts dividing $x=x_1\cdot x_2$ etc. and the process ends because $A$ is noetherian). Then, if irreducibles are prime, one can check that the factorization is unique up to order and invertibles.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element) says

> In an integral domain, every prime element is irreducible, but the converse is not true in general. The converse is true for unique factorization domains (or, more generally, [GCD domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain)).